# Configure SharePoint 2016 in a single server

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

I have installed SharePoint 2016 and SQL in the same server. While configuring Central Admin through SP Management shell i am getting error saying.. `Cannot connect to the database master at SQL Server at [Sever Name]. The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it` when creating a configuration DB. What are the steps i need to follow or what access i need to get? 
Any Idea?

Comment: Please provide your SP Management Shell to configure CentralAdministration. Did you already successfully create a Configuration Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check followings:

1. Check the permissions for the Setup account which you are using to
   run the wizard or PowerShell. Make sure the setup account is granted
   with "DB_Creator" and "Security_Admin" Server Roles.
2. In case of Named instance, it should be "Server\InstanceName". If it
   is SQL Alias, make sure the alias is properly configured and should
   be accessible from SharePoint Server.
3. Verify if the SQL Server Alias is created for both 32 and 64-bit!
   How to Create SQL Server Alias for SharePoint Check if the SQL
   Server Service is running on your Database Server. Verify "TCP/IP"
   protocol is enabled under Network Configuration section of SQL
   Server Configuration Manager.
4. Test the connectivity between SharePoint and SQL Server. Try adding
   a HOST file entry in your SharePoint Server to point the SQL
   Server's IP!
5. Check the firewall rules on SQL Server. If firewall is enabled on
   SQL Server, Create inbound TCP rule with ports: 1433,2383,2382 (or
   whatever dynamic port your SQL server is running) and inbound UPD
   rule with port: 1434.
6. Double check if you have not fat-fingered User Name or Password!

Comment: In my case, enabling TCP/IP protocol made it work. Thanks!!

Comment: @user85454 Mark as answer if it helps